# Parsing XML file using Pig

Tags: xml, apache-pig

I am trying to read a multilevel xml using pig by using following pig script

```
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
data = LOAD './a01.xml'
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader(
'p'
 ) AS
(s:chararray);
fdata=foreach data GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(s,'<p>\\n\\<s>\\n\\s*       <w>(.*)</w>\\n\\<\s>\\n\\<\p>')) as (w:chararray);
dump fdata;
```

but i am unable to read the xml file using the script
this is the structure of my input xml file

```
    -<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">



    -<text decls="A" xml:id="A01">


    -<body>


    -<p>


    -<s n="1">

    <w type="AT">The</w>

    <w type="NP" subtype="TL">Fulton</w>

    <w type="NN" subtype="TL">County</w>

    <w type="JJ" subtype="TL">Grand</w>

    <w type="NN" subtype="TL">Jury</w>

    <w type="VBD">said</w>

    <w type="NR">Friday</w>

    <w type="AT">an</w>

    <w type="NN">investigation</w>

    <w type="IN">of</w>

    <w type="NPg">Atlanta's</w>

    <w type="JJ">recent</w>

    <w type="NN">primary</w>

    <w type="NN">election</w>

    <w type="VBD">produced</w>

    <c type="pct">``</c>

    <w type="AT">no</w>

    <w type="NN">evidence</w>

    <c type="pct">''</c>

    </s>

    </p>
```

please let me know what is wrong with the pig expression

Update - i want to read only tag values with w type

Answer (score 0):

Try using Streaming XML Loader ..that would free you from writing UDFs.link http://blog.mortardata.com/post/61678005593/xml-pig-loader